# Auto adjust div height to fill space - CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I have a top header `<div id="header"></div>`, a middle part `<div id="content"></div>` and a bottom footer `<div id="footer"></div>`.

Header and footer has fixed heights 50px. I want to fix the positions of header and footer on top and bottom and I want to stretch the middle part (content) to fill the remaining space.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it by defining the style as below;

```
#header, #content, #footer {
    position: absolute;
}
#header{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#content {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

You can see my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/5pcCs/)**

Thanks @rocky3000 and @Mika for support **`:)`**

Answer (score 3):

You can use position: absolute on footer and header an then position the footer with bottom: 0px. I would do it this way:

```
#header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#content {
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: True! I was messing arround with this but completeley forgot about the `margin:-value`

Comment: Id just change the postition from absolute to fixed.

Comment: sorry.. i got a bug just now.. its okay in the case of header and footer.. but middle piece is not working/stretching..

Comment: I've changed positioning of #footer an #header to fixed like @kevin9794 suggested, removed bottom: 50px; from #content and removed definitions for body tag. Does it now work?

Answer (score 0):

Search for sticky footers [LINK](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) here on stackoverflow or with google and the problem is gone.

Comment: its just in the case of footer.. i want to stretch div in between header and footer

Comment: Why do you want to stretch the div between the header and the footer? Please, can you explain this?

Comment: hm, the easiest way to solve your problem is via js. But if you checked my link, the css is for the content div nearly the same as the other answer...the content div fit to its content and the footer alwas stays under the content div or if the content div height is too small on the bottom of the page...