# filling space between divs

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.content {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

.footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Header and footer look as I wish but now I'd like the content to fill all the space between them (with 30px margin all around). What should I add to it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto adjust div height to fill space - CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530634/auto-adjust-div-height-to-fill-space-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try height 100% on the content div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.header, .content, .footer {
    position: absolute;
}
.header{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.content {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #FF6600;
}
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #6600CC;
}
```